# Is it possible to cache computed observable in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to cache the computed observable value for certain time (1-2 sec). Is it possible to do some thing similar using extenders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom version of the computed observable object by wrapping it and replacing some of the functions.

[See this article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html) for an example of the approach. It's not used to do exactly what you ask, but the general idea should work. Simply replace the functionality showcased in the article with something which caches the data into a variable with a timestamp variable.

Though I think it should be noted that unless you're doing very heavy calculation or some other demanding tasks, I don't think you will be able to gain a huge benefit from caching the value.

Comment: Since knockout 2.0 this has been formalized with [extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)